how to disable touch pad’s scroll inertia?
I have a scroll snap code that uses the GSAP ScrollTrigger and ScrollTo plugins. The code works perfectly with a mouse, but when I use a touchpad and perform a large scroll, the snap occurs, However after its completion it continues to scroll to the next section due to the momentum. How can I disable this momentum?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>debag</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hero-section">
        <h1>hero section</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="scrollTarget" class="features-benefits-section">
        <h1>features & benefits section</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>

body{
    background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
section{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.hero-section{
    background-color: rgb(156, 76, 76);
}
.features-benefits-section{
    background-color: rgb(163, 2, 2);
}
h1{
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 5rem;
}

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, ScrollToPlugin);

ScrollTrigger.create({
  trigger: ".hero-section",
  markers: true,
  start: "75% top",//changing the starting point of the scroll snap
  end: "bottom bottom",
  onEnter: () => {
      gsap.to(window, {
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "power1",
        scrollTo: {
          y: "#scrollTarget",
          autoKill: false
        }
      });
  }
});


important note: if using this solution don't style directly the html tag (only style the body), for some reason that causes a bag
Found the answer! After the snap scrolling is finished, change the body styling through the DOM for 1 second to have overflow-y: hidden and a height of 100vh. This will make the site non-scrollable for one second, and all momentum will not have any effect. Here is the complete code:


gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger, ScrollToPlugin);

ScrollTrigger.create({
  trigger: ".hero-section",
  markers: true,
  start: "75% top",//changing the starting point of the scroll snap
  end: "bottom bottom",
  onEnter: () => {
      gsap.to(window, {
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: "power1",
        scrollTo: {
          y: "#scrollTarget",
          autoKill: false
        },
      onComplete: () => {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        document.body.style.height = '100vh';

        new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(() => {
        document.body.style.overflowY = 'visible';
        document.body.style.height = 'auto';
        });
      }
      });
  }
});
body{
    background-color: rgb(39, 39, 39);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scrollbar-width: 0px; /* Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

section{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.hero-section{
    background-color: rgb(156, 76, 76);
}
.features-benefits-section{
    background-color: rgb(163, 2, 2);
}
h1{
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 5rem;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>debag</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.0/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gsap@3.12.5/dist/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hero-section">
        <h1>hero section</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="scrollTarget" class="features-benefits-section">
        <h1>features & benefits section</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
    </section>
</body>
</html>



